# Spring boot data rest does not work with @XmlTransient

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

I developed spring boot rest data application.  It was working great until the client decided that they did not want an XML element in the response.  So the jpa object is annotated with jaxb annotations (javax.xml.bind.annotation).   I thought I could just put @XmlTransient on the get method/property and it would be excluded from the output but it does not.  Why? How do I exclude the jpa element from the XML output?  Is there something I am missing with Spring data rest?

Comment: Can you show some code and an example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve